# Xcode 8 autolayout constraints don't work in custom tableViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, uistoryboard, xcode8

I have an app that uses custom tableviewcells. When I use autolayout for subviews (e.g. UIImageView, UILabels) on runtime I dont see any of the subview even though the constraint lines are blue. Everything was fine before i updated to Xcode8.

Constraints work fine on in other views.

EDIT: Here is the screenshot. Imageview is not displayed at all, even though it has placeholder image by default and there are images in source to replace the placeholder.

[image]

EDIT: same code without constraints. 
[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of that storyboard scene, please?

Comment: As well as the screenshot, use the view debugger at runtime to understand where the missing views are.

Comment: posted an image

Comment: Are you setting the image with SDWebImage? And are you sure that you're setting the custom property of your image ie. `cell.customImageView` and not `cell.imageView`

Comment: My image view is linked to my customTVC controller. If i remove the imageView constraints, it displays fine. What is SDWebimage?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using custom table view cells and auto layout. Somehow when I called `[self.tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"]` the cell wouldn't show. However once I removed this line from the viewDidLoad: everything worked properly

It's not certain that you have things layed out this way but this is what worked for me. Also, if you use anything like an autoresizingmask, turn that off for your constraints to work. You could also try selecting the Content View of the cell in interface builder and deselect "Autoresizes Subviews".